# Creating a server-side script to fetch from

Tags: node.js

I want to fetch countries and cities from my front end, but I know first, I need to make a server-side script on the backend to be able to do so.

If geography is a mock package where I can do so, and this is the code I have thus far, how could I prepare my backend to receive these fetch requests?

```
app.get('/:locations', function (req, res) {
  Geography.init().then(function() {
    console.log(Geography)
    Geography.open(req.params.url).then(function(site) {
        console.log(Geography)
         site.analyze().then(function(results) {
            res.json(results)
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Would it look something like this? (incomplete, of course....)

```
select
    countries
    cities
```

Comment: It will be `req.params.locations` not `req.params.url` by the way. Anyway, I'd just give it a shot and then come back if you are having problems. [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/all-the-cities) is an example package for looking at cities etc.

Comment: @Pentium1080Ti Ah right, but I am wondering how to more prepare my server-side to send that information back to the front end?

Answer (score 0):

Taking the [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/all-the-cities) I used as an example in the comments:

In the example provided in the readme, a JSON reponse is returned of an array of cities matching the filter (or close to it) such as `[{}, {}, {}, ...]`

So, if you wanted to form a response from this, you could just take some of the data. For example, if you wanted to return the country along with a latitude and longitude you could do:

```js
// let "cities" be the JSON response from the library
// cities[0] is the first object in the array from the response
res.json({
    "country": cities[0].country,
    "location": {
        "lat": cities[0].loc[1], //longitude comes first
        "lon": cities[0].loc[0]
    }
});
```

You could implement this with your GET endpoint like:

```js
app.get('/:locations', function (req, res) {
    cities = citiesLibrary.filter(city => city.name.match(req.params.locations));
});
```

But if you wanted to return all the results returned by the library then you could simply just use:

```js
res.json(cities);
```